# Assign variable from perl to csh

Tags: perl, shell, csh

I have a csh script, my goal is to read an ini config file with perl module Config::Simple. I want to execute my perl command and assign the result to one variable.

```
perl -MConfig::Simple -e '$cfg = new Config::Simple("../config.ini"); $myvar = $cfg->param("myvar");'
```

What is the syntax ?

Comment: I am working on somebody else scripts...But you'r right, it is the best solution since Phil-H answer works. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Receive the script's return value into a variable? I con't know the csh syntax, but in bash that is:

```
myvar=`perl ....`;
```

But if you wanted to set several variables, not sure.

Answer (score 1):

For setting several variables you could have the perl script `print` csh syntax that the shell would evaluate.

I don't know csh but in bash it should be done like

```
#!/bin/sh
eval `perl -E 'say "FOO=123"; say "BAR=456"'`
echo "FOO is $FOO"
```

Answer (score 1):

Command substitution in `csh` looks like this:

```
#!/bin/csh
set VAR=`perl -E 'say q(hello world)'`
echo ${VAR}
```

And, as an aside, I hope your using a descendent of `csh` like `tcsh`. The original `csh` implementation is a brain-dead mangled shell.  This classic [paper](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/) describes why.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement, where I was using python instead of perl.
my python script was producing 3 output strings and the values were needed to be set in csh as variable.

Here's a solution.. hope it will help!

Inside Python:

> I was using three variables : x , y and z I had only
>   one print statement in python which printed: x,y,z

Inside CSH:

```
set py_opt = `./my_python_script`
set csh_x = `echo $py_opt | sed 's/,/ /g' | awk '{print $1}'`
set csh_y = `echo $py_opt | sed 's/,/ /g' | awk '{print $2}'`
set csh_z = `echo $py_opt | sed 's/,/ /g' | awk '{print $3}'`
```